# Database triggers to update one table based on another

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, triggers

I have 2 tables

1. customer (which contains customer_id as primary key etc)
2. order1 (which also contains order_id as primary key, customer_id as foreign key)

I was asked to write a trigger to update order1's customer_id whenever customer table's customer_id was updated.

Please help me to find the answer. 
Please write me the query for the question.

If you want more information, 
reply me.

I have not tried this before because I don't know what to do very weak in triggers as well as in database.

I don't have any idea about these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put pretty much any SQL you want in your trigger code.

For example a mysql trigger with a query which inserts data in a second table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_tru AFTER UPDATE ON some_table
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO someotherdatabase.someothertable
SELECT * FROM some_table AS tablealias WHERE tablealias.primarykey=new.primarykey; 
END;
```

Comment: please tell me and if possible write a oracle query for the question

Comment: and my question is if i update customer id 4 to 14 in customer table

Comment: someotherdatabase.someothertable is the dot notation in MySQL to indicate database (before the .) and table (after the .). The result is that you insert a result into a table in another database (I used this trigger for immediate archiving of transactions).

Comment: then in order1 table also customer id 4 should be changed to 14

Comment: my question is if one table has c_id=4 and another also has the same  if i change 4 as 14 in one table then the other table also 4 should be changed to 14